# Firebug programmatic breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, breakpoints

Is there any way to set a programmatic breakpoint in JavaScript, so that Firebug will stop executing code and I can continue step by step debug inside the Firebug.

Something similar to what is done in python like:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use the [`debugger` keyword](http://www.joehewitt.com/blog/goodbye_venkman.php).